# Python Class Variables' scope?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning Python (My background is C, C++).

In the following code from tutorialspoint.com:

```
class Employee:
   'Common base class for all employees'
   empCount = 0

   def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary
      Employee.empCount += 1
   
   def displayCount(self):
     print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

   def displayEmployee(self):
      print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary

"This would create first object of Employee class"
emp1 = Employee("Zara", 2000)
"This would create second object of Employee class"
emp2 = Employee("Manni", 5000)
emp1.displayEmployee()
emp2.displayEmployee()
print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount
```

(1) My confusion is in the instance variables 'self.name', self.salary'. I understand that variables in Pythons don't need an explicit declaration unlike C, but then how can these variables be used in the method 'displayEmployee', don't they have their own local scope which is the constructor method '_ *init* _'? Also, this 'self' variable, is an object for the class being created - so this would mean that the declaration of a class in Python also creates an object of that class (so no virtual classes like in C++) at the same time?

(2) My second (less important) question, is in the above code, how come the randomly placed strings "This would create first object of Employee class" and "This would create second object of Employee class", don't show an error? As far as I know, comments must begin with # or '''? Or are strings also viewed as whitespaces in Python?

Comment: Wait, are you using python 2?

Comment: Yes, sry should have mentioned that

Comment: It's end-of-life, so _probably_ not worth learning/using for much longer. Python3 would have the same answer, though

Comment: `self` is like `this` in C++

Comment: `self.name` isn't a variable, it's an expression that looks up the attribute `name` on the object given by `self`.  Only `self` has to be in scope to use this expression, and it is in fact one of the parameters to each of the methods that use it here.

Comment: (1) Please repeat your tutorial on classes and instances; include what you *specifically* do not understand from there.  (2) Just as with `C`, the expression is evaluated and discarded.

Comment: @Prune: This was on the first page on classes and instances. I think I was quite clear in my exact problem - which was how 'self.name' etc were used in a method other then the one where they were defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Creation of an object (i.e. `Emplyee()` calls the `__init__()` method, the initializer). All methods that then have the `self` argument take that object's *instance* to operate on. Meaning these methods will have access to that object's `self` variables. This means that *static* methods do not have access to this, and why accessing those instance variables does not error. As an example, this would error:

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = 123

    @staticmethod # Decorator to indicate this method should not accept 'self'
    def static_method():
        print(self.variable)
```

Because the method `static_method()` does not operate on an initialize instance of the `Employee` object.

2. Strings, like any other unassigned variable, will be interpreted and then discarded. Like the following:

```py
123
"test"
[1, 2]
```

These all do nothing, but given that they're *technically* valid statements these do not result in errors. You will often see this type of statement in docstrings, like:

```py
"""
Long string goes here.
"""
```

Comment: Worth mentioning triple quoted strings for documentation.

Comment: So the self variables - are all of them necessarily defined within init, or can some other methods also define variables to self?

Comment: Init is the initializer. New is the constructor. New should return a new instance every time, init can be used to reinitialize as many times as you want. `type.__call__` is what actually ensures both get called when you do `Employee()`

Comment: Instance variables do not *have* to be defined in the constructor of a class/object. It's best practice to, so you can get a better 'idea' of what instance methods exist within a class by just looking at the constructor, and you avoid potentionally encountering an `AttributeError` when referencing instance variables that aren't yet defined. However any instance method *can* create new instance variables if you choose to do so.

Comment: My final 2 followup questions:
(i) So if a new attribute of self eg self.a is defined in method 'displayCount' in my original code, then it can only be used by other functions, once 'displayCount' is called for that particular object?
(ii) Isn't it necessary for all methods of a class to necessarily have 'self' as the first argument? (that's what I read in the tutorial)

Comment: Docstrings are real strings. You can place a string (or integer, or any other object) anywhere, and get a no-op. But docstrings also get interpreted as comments by the interpreter if placed correctly.

Comment: Great point @MadPhysicist - corrected. @Kaind, (i) That's correct. Attempting to access an instance variable (attribute) that does not exist will raise an `AttributeError`, calling `displayCount()` which assigns/creates that variable would then stop this behavior (in your case). (ii) It is not necessary, but using `self` is more common than not. Think of a class that has some function that doesn't interact with any of that class's attributes/instance variables, you can make that method static and remove the `self` as the first argument.